# Software Routing

Tags: networking, virtual, router, host

"Commercial software routers from companies such as Vyatta can typically only attain transfer data at speeds of up to three gigabits per second. That isn’t fast enough to take advantage of the full speed of a typical network card, which operates at 10 gigabits per second." [[1]](https://www.technologyreview.com/s/420324/software-router-smashes-speed-records/)

How is the speed of the network interface card relevant in this scenario? Aren't software routers connecting multiple Virtual Machines running on the **same** physical host? [[2]](https://www.sdxcentral.com/resources/nfv/whats-a-virtual-router-vrouter/) Unless a PC has multiple network interface cards, it is unlikely that it functions as a packet switch between different physical hosts.

My interpretation suggests that there seem to exist two different kinds of software routing: (1) Embedding a real time operating system on an actual router. (2) Writing application layer code on a PC that can handle packets being transmitted between different virtual machines running on *that very* PC. Is this correct?

Comment: It has been my experience that most implementations of software routers, such as Vyatta, are to replace traditional routers in a network. Unfortunately, people are often disappointed by the performance, but there are people who swear by it, and they wouldn't think of using anything else.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what your router is doing. If it's literally just looking at a static route table and forwarding packets out another interface, there isn't much hit in performance.

It's when you get into things like NAT, Crypto, QoS, SPI... that you will see performance degradation. Hardware vendors are usually using custom silicon to process the more advanced features, this allows for higher throughput packet forwarding.

Now that merchant silicon is fast enough and the open source applications are getting better, the performance gap is closing.

It really depends on your use case as far as what you want to use. I've gone with both and not seen performance hits, but the software versions weren't handling high throughput workloads.

Answer (score 1):

Performance of the link from the virtual network to the physical eventually becomes important at any reasonable scale.  You're right that, within the same physical host, things can be pretty quick, but that requires that one can get everything needed in one box.

While merchant silicon has come a long way in improving the performance of networking equipment, greater gains are taking place getting CPU's to handle networking tasks better.  Both AMD and Intel have improved their architectures to the point where 10 Gbps forwarding is a reality.  Intel has developed a specialized library (DPDK [Wiki Page](http://dpdk.org/)) that takes care of a lot of low-level networking functions at high performance.

Comment: Unfortunately, 10 Gbps is nothing. Some of the boxes we use have 64 10 Gbps ports. Some sites have several of these, and these aren't even the data centers, which use multiple 40 or 100 Gbps channeled ports for aggregate of dozens of 10 Gbps ports. I know people who think they can replicate this sort of thing with FOSS and generic hardware, but they are usually disappointed. I agree this can work well, under certain circumstances, but large enterprise usually aren't included in that, despite what managers and business groups may think when they see the price tag for expanding things.

Comment: @RonMaupin  so basically, those boxes that you are referring to, are desktops or servers running a routing operating system and have multiple network interfaces installed? A desktop or server would only have one network interface, unlike a router, which has multiple, and can route packets between multiple physical hosts (and other routers).

Comment: @Zond, no, the boxes we use are real routers or layer-3 switches. I have seen people try to emulate this with large server equipment, using a bunch of multiport network cards. When you get to total throughput which is a fraction of what the enterprise routing and switching gear does, the server can't keep up. That's not to say it's not a good idea for some people, and it will keep advancing. It just depends on your needs.